# scala akka actors : Can Message be of type of String

Tags: scala, akka

I have been told that actors should not be passed strings but only objects. Is there any reason behind it?

The following code snippets seems fine to me? Any issues with it?

```
class MyActor extends Actor {
   def onRecieve(): Unit {
     case "xyz" => // do something
   }
}

class Main {
 // create a actor systesm
 // create a worker of type MyActor
 worker! "xyz"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings in Scala (really, java.lang.String) are objects. Strings also implement java.io.Serializable, which Akka requires for messages. Generally speaking, though, it's best if Akka actors receive messages that are case classes or case objects. This is because the receive() method of the actor does a pattern match, and it needs to deconstruct the object using unapply(). This is what case classes provide. For case objects, you can still pattern match on the type itself. Of course, pattern matching on string literals should technically work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Strings can be misspelled, they can't include parameters (unless you start parsing the strings), and the compiler can't check for missing cases.

To check for missing cases with a case class, have your case class messages all extend a sealed trait, then first match for the trait and then do a nested match on the subtypes of the trait. Then you should get a warning if you don't handle all subtypes of the trait.

But yes, strings do work fine as messages. case classes have some advantages but strings work.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: yes, a string is a completely valid message to send to an Akka actor (in Akka Typed, of course, this would only be valid with an `ActorRef[String]`, `ActorRef[AnyRef]`, or `ActorRef[Any]` (or an `ActorRef[T]` given that there's an implicit conversion from `String` to `T` available): at least two of those three are pretty weird... the only possible parametric behavior for `ActorRef[AnyRef]` or `ActorRef[Any]` is ignoring every message).

However, keep in mind [Alan Perlis's 34th epigram of programming](https://cpsc.yale.edu/epigrams-programming):

> The string is a stark data structure and everywhere it is passed there is much duplication of process. It is a perfect vehicle for hiding information.

In order to extract meaning from a string, it generally must be parsed: even efficient parsers can be expected to be less efficient than following references in an object graph, but these parsers make up for that inefficiency by also imposing a heavy cognitive load on anyone trying to understand what's going on.